# convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n\cdot n!}{n^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to determine the convergence for 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n\cdot n!}{n^n} $$

$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n] {u_n} = \lim_\limits{n \to \infty } 3 {\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}}$ , because $n! \le n^n$, so $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n] {u_n} = 0 < 1$, then it converges?

Comment: All you have shown is the limit is no bigger than 3.

Comment: The ratio test works well here. ${a_{n+1} \over a_n} \to {3 \over e}$. We know that $e < 3$.

Comment: The root test (or better, the comparison test) also works, but one needs Stirling's estimate of the factorial; the ratio test (as copper.hat suggests) works particularly well here because the 'classical' definition of $e$ appears almost directly in the limit.